# Stuck with nav html css - how to get it full width

Tags: html, css

I've got a nav here:

http://tumolo.co.uk/navbar/

I've tried all sorts - but I cant get this nav to fill up the browser 100% width. It has white space on both Left and Right side of the navbar.

I put each nav li to 16% as it's 100% / 6 menu elements, 16% is the closest to get each element equal size.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.nav li {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em !important;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
.nav ul li#wind a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5da3ab;
}
.nav ul li#wind .active {
  background-color: #5da3ab;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#hmrc a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ac5e88;
}
.nav ul li#hmrc .active {
  background-color: #ac5e88;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#cvl a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5e7ea4;
}
.nav ul li#mvl a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5b3e52;
}
.nav ul li#admin a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #7c6e61;
}
.nav ul li#liquid a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #7c4c4c;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 16%;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-right: 1px solid #ebe3e3;
  }
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
  .nav li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
  }
  /* Options 2 - Float
    .nav li {
    float: left;
    }
    .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .nav {
    background-color: #444;
    }
    */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="wind"><a href="#">Winding up petition</a>
    </li>
    <li id="hmrc"><a href="#">Cant pay HMRC?</a>
    </li>
    <li id="cvl"><a href="#">CVA</a>
    </li>
    <li id="mvl"><a href="#">MVL</a>
    </li>
    <li id="admin"><a href="#">Administration</a>
    </li>
    <li id="liquid"><a href="#">Liquidation</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will get you there!

```
.nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

If you're wanting the ends to be flush against the edge, it may be better to use:

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

Looking at the existing styles on the element, you can remove the `padding-left` and `padding-right`, as mentioned in the comments.  Also, with `flex`, you may want to check out vendor prefixes.

**Note:** Support for old IE can be shaky.

The above does leave gaps in the header, as also mentioned in the comments.  An alternative, suggested by Joe, is:

```
#navList {
  display:flex;
}
#navList li {
  flex:1 auto;
}
```

Comment: `justify-content: space-around;`... ew.  Why not just add `flex: 1 auto;` to `.nav li`?  Also, `#navlist` needs `padding:0;`

Comment: @JosephMarikle Styling by id is often considered [bad form](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/).  The styles as is works, I pasted them into his stylesheet to verify, though removing the `padding-right` does get rid of unneeded styles.  The `flex:1 auto` might work, this approach was just the first that came to mind :)

Comment: the left side looks good guys, but it just looks like if I applied float:left;

Comment: @MatthewJohnson I wasn't saying to style with the ID.  I was referencing the element that needs the style by the ID because it already has a style in OP's stylesheet and was the highest one in developer tools.  It would ideally go in the `.nav ul` style.  Also, I'm not sure what you're testing on, but in Chrome 52 on Mac, the padding results in whitespace leaving a huge gap.  Also, without a `flex` property, in chrome it collapses the nav elements looking very cramped.

Comment: @LeeYip Adding `padding:0` to the unordered list fixes that.

Comment: @LeeYip `justify-content:space-between` is works better I think.

Comment: @LeeYip Oops.  I misspoke.  `flex: 1 auto;` fixes the gap on the right.  The problem is that without it, the browser is still trying to use the 16% width, which is too short to fill the whole bar.  It's shorthand for "allow to grow, allow to shrink, and use `auto` for the width".  (i.e. `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: auto;`)

Comment: @JosephMarikle Fair point about it already in the stylesheet.  The `flex` with `space-between`, along with the width set to 100%, fills the whole bar.  There may be gaps between the elements, but that could be adjusted for.  Didn't test that last comment, but assuming that works I'd say dump the 16% and roll with that.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson That's the reason why I suggested `flex: 1 auto`. `justify-content:space-between` leaves unclickable gaps between the links, but `flex-grow: 1` with `flex-basis: auto` adjusts for that automatically.  I could be misinterpreting OP's intent, but I assume the gaps are not desired.  All that being said, you're approach is I think the the best option, provided older IE support is not needed (which I kind of presume nowadays).

Comment: @JosephMarikle Probably true.

Comment: @LeeYip You should add the HTML and current styles to your question.  Links to sites are frowned upon.  I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not absolutely necessary, I'd ditch `display: inline-block;` on the `.nav li` - it messes with width calculations, as you know since you've adjusted for it with the -4px on each, which is only an approximation.

If you float the `.nav li` left, add `box-sizing: border-box;` and increase the width to 16.6667%, you'll get total coverage. You'll have to adjust `.nav ul` to contain it properly, but I've updated the snippet below to show.

```css
body {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav ul {
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.nav a {
    color: #6b6b6b;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8em !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ff0;
    color: #000;
}
.nav a.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
    cursor: default;
}
.nav ul li#wind a:hover {
    background-color: #5da3ab;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#wind .active {
    background-color: #5da3ab;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#hmrc a:hover {
    background-color: #ac5e88;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#hmrc .active {
    background-color: #ac5e88;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#cvl a:hover {
    background-color: #5e7ea4;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#mvl a:hover {
    background-color: #5b3e52;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#admin a:hover {
    background-color: #7c6e61;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#liquid a:hover {
    background-color: #7c4c4c;
    color: #ffffff;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.nav li {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    border-right: 1px solid #ebe3e3;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 16.6667%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
.nav li:last-child {
    border-right: 0 none;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"> 
 <ul id="navlist"> 
  <li id="wind"><a href="http://propertycrowdinvestor.com/insolvency/winding-up-petition/">Winding up petition</a></li> 
  <li id="hmrc"><a href="http://propertycrowdinvestor.com/insolvency/cant-pay-hmrc/">Cant pay HMRC?</a></li> 
  <li id="cvl"><a href="http://propertycrowdinvestor.com/insolvency/cvl/">CVA</a></li> <li id="mvl"><a href="http://propertycrowdinvestor.com/insolvency/mvl/">MVL</a></li> 
  <li id="admin"><a href="http://propertycrowdinvestor.com/insolvency/administration/">Administration</a></li> 
  <li id="liquid"><a href="http://propertycrowdinvestor.com/insolvency/liquidation/">Liquidation</a></li> 
 </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: You sure can. I've edited my answer with your code above.

Comment: however, there's about a 1px of white on the left hand side - how do i get rid of that? I've posted my original code above now .... thx (obvs changed it to 16.6% width now)

Comment: Daniel - 100% bang on! Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool. Mark it as answered! :)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your explanation, you are trying to make a header navigation that has 100% width and the nodes of the menu will have the same width;

You should use `calc()` let me give you an example and you can apply that to your code;

```
<div class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>Element</li>
      <li>Element</li>
      <li>Element</li>
      <li>Element</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Also in your CSS;

```
.nav { height:30px; width:100%; 
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
.nav li { 
  width:calc(100% / 4); 
  list-style: none; 
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
```

We divided %100 to 4 because **we have 4 li elements** in our navigation.

Check on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9b1re2p/1/

Hoping that would help, please post your code as it is simplified in your question with a better explanation next time.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS table. It behaves much like the flex box but with better support.

It will space out each li equally up and down without the need for the 16% media query.

You will just need to tweak the styling of the links a little to add in your border.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.nav li {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em !important;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
.nav ul li#wind a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5da3ab;
}
.nav ul li#wind .active {
  background-color: #5da3ab;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#hmrc a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ac5e88;
}
.nav ul li#hmrc .active {
  background-color: #ac5e88;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.nav ul li#cvl a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5e7ea4;
}
.nav ul li#mvl a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5b3e52;
}
.nav ul li#admin a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #7c6e61;
}
.nav ul li#liquid a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #7c4c4c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="wind"><a href="#">Winding up petition</a>
    </li>
    <li id="hmrc"><a href="#">Cant pay HMRC?</a>
    </li>
    <li id="cvl"><a href="#">CVA</a>
    </li>
    <li id="mvl"><a href="#">MVL</a>
    </li>
    <li id="admin"><a href="#">Administration</a>
    </li>
    <li id="liquid"><a href="#">Liquidation</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```